# SQL Query with arithmetic

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am working on a query and am getting this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\getAssets.php on line 19
```

I know for a fact that my query is wrong and I just can't figure out why. It is probably something dumb and I have just been looking at it way too long.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM location WHERE ((320000 * ABS(SQRT(SQUARE(xCoor - "' . $_POST['latitude'] .'" ) + SQUARE(yCoor - "' . $_POST['longitude'] .'" ))) < 50)');
```

Your second pair of eyes is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if(!$result){ die(mysqli_error($con)); }`  Never, ever, assume a MySQL query worked.  *Always* check for errors.  If the tutorial you are using don't tell you to use `mysqli_error`, then it's wrong.

Comment: Does it work from the command line / phpmyadmin? What does the complete string look like? sql injection.

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but if you googled "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given", you'd find tons of posts with help.

Comment: You aren't being mean, you just aren't reading the question... There is a syntax error in my query and I just can't figure it out...

Comment: @Chitowns24 - if you echo out the query and run it in the database; or use `mysqli_error()`, then the database will show you exactly where the syntax error is.

Comment: (@Chitowns24 - for what it's worth, there's an unclosed bracket somewhere in your query)

Comment: Thank you Andrew, the first piece of useful advice. When using the phpMyAdmin SQL area I found that the SQUARE function doesn't exist for mysql so I need to do some more research. And I had a couple misplaced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is syntactically wrong: you should probably write it like this (no single quotes needed):

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM location WHERE ((320000 * ABS(SQRT(SQUARE(xCoor - " . $_POST['latitude'] . ") + SQUARE(yCoor - " . $_POST['longitude'] . " ))) < 50)");
```

Of course $_POST['latitude'] and $_POST['longitude'] *MUST* be numbers...

You should also add the mysqli_fetch_array code you are using, because the code you gave can't produce such an error... :-)

As a general rule, $result (a result set) should be passed to mysqli_fetch_array() ...

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM location WHERE ((320000 * ABS(SQRT(SQUARE(xCoor - " . $_POST['latitude'] . ") + SQUARE(yCoor - " . $_POST['longitude'] . " ))) < 50)");
if (!$rs) {
    die(mysqli_error());
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
     $field1 = $row["field1"];
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there was a syntax error and I found it. Also no Square function in mysql so I will figure that out on my own